# Light flicker dimming aftermarket stereo

Tags: headlight, aftermarket-upgrade

My relative hook up after Market stereo,amp and subwoofer it worked for six months than all of a sudden my headlights and interior lights start flicker dimming and that's just turning the power to the stereo on not playing any music and it start flicker dim. But if I take out the fuse to the amplifier lights work just fine. Can somebody help me out what could be causing that problem? Please and thank you.  2004 buick lesabre

Comment: Are you talking about your headlights?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes the headlights, dashboard lights basically all of them. Do you maybe think it could be the wiring?